# How to reference the "next" command line argument in a bash script for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a simple bash script that uses if and else statements to print out the calendar using the cal command.

Here's my code:

```
  #!/bin/sh

  for f in $*
  do
      #if input $f is a number use it
      if [ $f -eq $f ]; then
          cal $f
      #if it's not a number then print cal and assume there's a year right after it ($2)
      else
          cal $f $2
      fi
  done
```

This sort of works. If I do "./mycal 2008" it'll print out the year 2008 without complaint. However if I do "./mycal june 2008" I'd like it to just print out the month June 2008.

My for loop is set up incorrectly though. What happens is

1. mycal prints out June 2008
2. mycal prints out the entire year 2008.

This is because of my for loop - after it prints June 2008 it goes to the next command line input, which is 2008 (a number) so it prints the entire year 2008.

Is there any way to avoid this? I could probably break or exit the program as soon as either of the conditionals evaluates as true, but I'd like to be able to do things like

./mycal June 2007 March 2005 September 2022 which would

1. print June 2007
2. print March 2005
3. print September 2022

With a language like C I could probably do something like this.

```
for (x=0; x< length(argArray); x++)
{
    //argArray[x] is a string like "june" or something
    if (isNotInt(argArray[x]))
    {
        //cal month + year
        cal ( argArray[x], argArray[x+1] );
        x++; //move to the next arg, skip x+1 because it's a year we just used
    }  
    //argArray[x] is a number, print it.
    else
    {
        cal ( argArray[x] );
    }
}
```

Any ideas? It would be nice if I could access items with array indices in shell scripting. I'm very new to sh scripts, thanks for the help!

Comment: `for f in "$@"; do`... Using `"$@"` allows arguments that include spaces.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not related to the question but correct as a general practice. OP appears to be trying to have two arguments and not one.

Comment: See the manual loop in [Bash FAQ 035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) for an approach to this sort of thing.

Comment: @EtanReisner That was in answer to his *However if I do "./mycal june 2008" I'd like it to just print out the month June 2008.* I may have misunderstood looking at it a second time...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Except that it would only be relevant if he wanted to write `./mycal 'june 2008'`. (That said, a good answer would probably suggest that he write `./mycal 'june 2008'`, and then explain how to make that work properly.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Right but that's supposed to be the `$2` using block, not a single string argument to `cal`. That said I can't find a version of `cal` that takes month names at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `while` loop to iterate over the argument list, shifting as necessary. Looking at the first argument, if it's a year, we just call `cal` immediately. Otherwise, we look at the next argument. If *it* is a year, we call call with two arguments, otherwise just with the current argument.

```bash
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    month_or_year=$1
    shift
    # bash only: if [[ $month_or_year =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
    if expr "$month_or_year" : '[0-9][0-9]*' > /dev/null; then
        # Just a year
        cal "$month_or_year"
    # bash only: if (( $# )) && [[ $month_or_year =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
    elif [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && expr "$1" : '[0-9][0-9]*' > /dev/null; then
        # A month and a year
        month=$month_or_year
        year=$1
        shift
        cal "$month" "$year"
    else
       # Just a month
        cal "$month_or_year"
    fi
done
```

---

Depending on your actual version of `cal`, you may need to convert the month to a number. I'd use a case statement like

```
case $month in
    jan|January) month=1 ;;
    feb) month=2 ;;
    mar) month=3 ;;
    apr) month=4 ;;
    may) month=5 ;;
    jun) month=6 ;;
    jul) month=7 ;;
    aug) month=8 ;;
    sep) month=9 ;;
    oct) month=10 ;;
    nov) month=11 ;;
    dec) month=12 ;;
    *) printf 'Unrecognized month: %s\n' "$month_or_year"; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

Adjust the cases for the arguments you want to accept. Labels are case sensitive, and January provides an example of accepting alternative names for a month.

Comment: Thanks for the response @chepner, I tried out your code and I get an odd error:

'./myCal june 2009'

'./myCal: 3: ./myCal: 2: not found'


I presume this is because it's trying to 'shift' but the last argument is '2009' which is argument 1? 

If it matters I'm using #!/bin/sh.

Comment: If you're actually using `bash`, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, but I'll update the answer to avoid using bashisms like `(( ... ))`.

Comment: I realized what the problem was - I was using #!/bin/sh, not #!/bin/bash. I'm not entirely sure what the difference is, but I'm restricted to 'sh.' I'm assuming the while loop is written incorrectly or something.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I just saw your comment.

Comment: I also used `$2` where, after using `shift`, I should have used `$1`. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, it runs now, but I noticed that if I do ./myCal july it'll still manage to fall into the first if statement, and attempt to do "cal july" which of course doesn't work because there is no year after july. The regexp looks okay to me but the if statement is a bit confusing. Could that be causing the issue? If I put an "echo "hi" " inside that if statement I can see that it says "hi" whenever I do ./myCal july

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted that. I got rid of the else statement since cal can't print out a plain old month. ./myCal june does nothing now, which is perfect. ./myCal june 2009 however just prints out the entire calendar year for 2009, not the month June in 2009. Any ideas?

Comment: That's what I get for not actually trying to run this. I overlooked the fact that `cal` doesn't take string month names.

Comment: Heh, I actually fixed that issue by changing the command to be 'cal "$month_or_year" 2015' so it prints out the month from this year. Problem is, ./myCal june 2009 just prints out June 2015 and then the year 2009.